# How can I customise Pretty_Printed JSON in PHP 7.x?

Tags: php, json, pretty-print

PHP's built-in `PRETTY_PRINT` doesn't allow for much customisation beyond a few additional flags:

- `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`
- `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

But the kind of customisation I am looking for is one that transforms the displayed JSON, so that it ends up looking:

- *less horizontal*

  - 2-space indents instead of 4
- *more vertical*

  - newlines at the start of arrays & objects
  - newlines between same-level arrays & objects
  - newlines between same-level entries

So instead of the horizontally spaced out:

```
[
    {
        "berry": "banana",
        "description": [
            "yellow",
            "sweet"
        ],
        "notes": []
      },
      {
        "berry": "aubergine",
        "taste": [
            "purple",
            "bitter"
        ],
        "notes": []
      }
]
```

I can have the vertically spaced out:

```
[
  {
    "berry": "banana",

    "description": [

      "yellow",
      "sweet"
    ],

    "notes": []
  },


  {
    "berry": "aubergine",

    "description": [

      "purple",
      "bitter"
    ],

    "notes": []
  }
]
```

Is there anything in `PHP 7.x` which would enable me to customise the output of pretty-printed JSON?

---

**Historical Note:**

The classic reference to reformatting JSON in PHP is [Format JSON With PHP](https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/) by **Dave Perrett**.

This dates from 2008, pre-dating even the `PRETTY_PRINT` flag (which arrived 4 years later in 2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any specific additions to pretty printing JSON in PHP 7.x, but it strikes me that I can:

- use the `PRETTY_PRINT` flag
- *then* follow up with a series of `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` to achieve my customised output (as outlined in the question at the top)

**Example:**

```
function Custom_Pretty_Print_JSON($Data) {

  if (!is_null(json_decode($Data, TRUE))) {

    $Data = json_decode($Data, TRUE);
  }

  $String = json_encode($Data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

  $String = str_replace('    ', '  ', $String);

  $String = preg_replace("/(\:\s\{|\:\s\[|\,)\n([\s]+)(\"|\{|\[)/", "$1\n\n$2$3", $String);

  return $String;
}
```